# Nested For Loop Variables Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, nested

Here is my code

```
set list=test
del /Q failed_tests.txt
FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    %%a > output_%%a.txt 

    FINDSTR /C:"[----------]" output_%%a.txt > check_run.txt

    for /f "delims=" %%x in (check_run.txt) do (
        set content=%%x
    )

    if not %content%=="[----------]" (
        echo Test Does Not Run >> failed_tests.txt
    ) else (
        echo Test Runs >> failed_tests.txt
    )
)
type failed_tests.txt
```

`content` seems to always be set to `"[----------]"`. However when `output_test.txt`/`check_run.txt` doesn't contain `"[----------]"` it should be set to an empty string.

Comment: 1. Force `set "content="` before `for /f "delims=" %%x` loop. 2.You need to enable [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and then use `if not "!content!"=="[----------]"` (note proper quoting). Force `echo ON` to see what happen...

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: @JosefZ what if I want to add a for loop inside of the else statement that does something similar. Would I need to create another "content" like variable or and would I need to enable Delayed Expansion again?

Comment: @emilk No, you don't need to enable delayed expansion again. It is in effect until next ENDLOCAL statement. Add another variable if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Incorporating @JosefZ's suggestions into an answer so this shows as answered.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set list=test
del /Q failed_tests.txt
FOR %%a IN (%list%) DO (
    %%a > output_%%a.txt 

    FINDSTR /C:"[----------]" output_%%a.txt > check_run.txt

    set "content="
    for /f "delims=" %%x in (check_run.txt) do (
        set "content=%%x"
    )

    if not "!content!"=="[----------]" (
        echo Test Does Not Run >> failed_tests.txt
    ) else (
        echo Test Runs >> failed_tests.txt
    )
)
type failed_tests.txt
```

**Edit:** Retaining cautionary double-quotes as per comment.

Comment: "no need for double quotes when clearing a variable (just set content= is fine)." - In theory. Unfortunately, some editors retain trailing spaces, so `set content=` may seem fine, but if there are trailing spaces on the line, those spaces will be assigned to the variable. Since they tend to invisibility when `echo`ed, they can be hard to detect. hence the quoted version - which has become normal practice on SO - it guards agains superfluous trailing spaces.